# Parse Yahoo finance data in C++

Tags: c++, csv, io, yahoo

I would like to parse Yahoo financial csv files in C++. Given that each line is formatted as:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
```

what is an efficient way to get these values? I would like to store the date into a structure that contains a ctime struct for the date, and doubles for all other values.

Comment: Duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You could define a struct for line, for example:

```
struct Instrument
{
   ctime   date_;
   double  open_;
   double  high_;
   double  low_;
   double  close_;
   double  volume_;
   double  adj_;
   double  close_;
};
```

Then you getline to read each line from file, parse each line(use boost tokenizer, regex or [split-a-c++-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)) into an Instrument object, then you could store it in a STL container, for example:

```
std::vector<Instrument> instruments;
instruments.push_back(instrument);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Boost Regular expressions can help you.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html